# jQuery margin-left of each previous element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, each, children

I have 5 images and on click I am trying to animate them next to each other, 50px apart.

Currently I am animating the first child and all the others 50px left but all on top of each other.

Here is my script:

```
var fadedur = 200,
    fadeop = 0.5,
    imgwidth = 220,
    imgleft = 40,
    imgfirst = -200,
    imgfh = -100;

$('img').on('click', function(){
    $('img').css('position','absolute').css('display','block');

    $('.cs').find(':first-child').stop().animate({
            "marginLeft": imgfirst,
            "margin-top": imgfh,
        }, 300);

    $('.cs').find(':first-child').next('img').each(function() {         
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "marginLeft": imgfirst + imgwidth + imgleft,  // imgfirst should
            "margin-top": imgfh,                          // be something that
        }, 300);                                          // states prev()
    });

});​
```

and this is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/STgQC/

I am trying to make them look like this:

[image]

So basically I need something that would say:

**Animate to position of previous element + image width + 50px left.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.cs').find(':first-child').next('img')` will at most match one element so its pointless to call each on it.
Check out this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/STgQC/1/, is this the behaviour you're looking for?

Comment: If the first image *needed* to do something different, you could also use .nextAll('img') to get the full collection of images after the first one.

Answer (score 2):

`.each()` iterates through the result of `next()`. In your case, `next()` only returns the first image. So, your code only iterates over 1 image.

I would combine the 2 iterations into 1 logical one.

Try the following (worked for me):
Also Fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/mYRdU/1/

```
var fadedur = 200,
    fadeop = 0.5,
    imgwidth = 220,
    imgleft = 40,
    imgfirst = -200,
    imgfh = -100;

$('img').on('click', function(){    
    $('img').css('position','absolute').css('display','block');

    var newLeft = imgfirst;

    $('.cs').find('img').each(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "marginLeft": newLeft,//imgfirst + imgwidth + imgleft,
            "margin-top": imgfh,
        }, 300);

        newLeft += imgwidth + imgleft;
    });                 
});​
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking but Musa answers a correct solution first so I will be accepting his answer as the solution for my question. Thank you.